# In Angular How to auto-scroll on bottom to a new added element if my content overflows window height ? Applicable for the whole page, app

Tags: angular, overflow, autoscroll

IN ANGULAR
For example ... When trough form I add dozens of new divs or cards or whatever elements!
I just want that my page auto scrolls to the last element when I add a new element which will vertically overflow window height ...
 Applicable for the whole page, app

Tnx

Comment: Welcome to SO the code factory, please hold the line... . ok, just kidding. You should provide your code What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same idea to scroll to an element which is selected on some view. You can adjust it to tour purpose to scroll to last added.
So I created a directive with a possibility to pass a class name as parameter.

scroll-to-selected.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Renderer2, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollToSelected]'
})
export class ScrollToSelectedDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() scrollToClass: string;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains(this.scrollToClass)) {
      this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
    }
  }
}
```

and the list-item.component.ts itself:

```
<div class="list-item"
     *ngIf="lostItems$ | async as listItem"
     scrollToSelected
     [scrollToClass]="'selected'"
     [class.selected]="listItem.isSelected">
...
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the "divs or cards" using [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren). Then in the ngAfterViewInit you can subscribe to changes and make a focus. but you need give a breath to Angular, so you enclosed the focus in a setTimeout

```
  @ViewChildren('itemID') itemsElement:QueryList<ElementRef> //<--we has here
                              //a QueryList with all our elements
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.itemsElement.changes.subscribe(res=>{
      //in res.last we has the last element
      setTimeout(()=>{
        res.last.nativeElement.focus()
      })
    })
  }
```

You simple .html

```
<button (click)="items.push(1)">add</button>
 <!--see how use a "reference variable" #itemID -->
 <!--be carefull, the div must has "tabindex"-->
<div tabindex="1" #itemID style="height:4rem" 
    *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">*{{i}}
</div>
```

An example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t58sjx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: If you place your DOM into ng-container you need use this code to get last HTML element with scroll method:
res._results[res._results.length - 1].nativeElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.scrollIntoView();